# Naming function with "proceed"

Tags: naming, clean-code, functions, naming-standards

I am wondering if it is good practice to name function which does the main logic "proceed" + "functionName".

I would use that name if there are some checks(if-s, try-catches, etc.) in the beginning of the function
and I would like to separate main logic into separate function.

**Example:**

```
private void function() {

    if(someCondition1) {
        throw Error1;
    }
    if(someCondition2) {
        throw Error2;
    }
    
    try {
        proceedFunction(); // <-- Name of the function here
    } catch(Exception e) {
         // Error handling
    }
}

private void proceedFunction() {
    // Main logic
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The content of your alleged `proceedFunction` is, in fact, described by `function`. What you're doing outside of the `proceedFunction` (but still in `function`) are some preliminary validations.

Currently, you're thinking of it like this:

```
myFunction = method body + [proceedMyFunction]
```

I suggest reframing your mindset, so the that name ("function") more closely describes the actual function being done, i.e.:

```
myFunction = [validateMyFunction] + method body
```

In other words, your code would be something like this:

```
private void Foo()
{
    ValidateFoo();

    // do the Foo work here
}

private void ValidateFoo()
{
    if (x == 5)
        throw new Exception("x is 5!");
}
```

Now, both `Foo` and `ValidateFoo` aptly describe what's happening inside their method bodies.

---

Do you *need* to separate the validation from the actual work? That's contextual.

If both parts are trivial and short, it may not be necessary to actually split them.
If either part is less than trivial, splitting them may significantly improve readability. It obviously also increases reusability when needed.

Answer (score 1):

While this is relatively subjective and opinionated and might be closed as such, I'll try to answer, not with a direct yes or no but with a more general criterion.

When you find yourself debating naming conventions, the first question you need to ask is "who is going to be reading this code". Try to think beyond who ia *currently* reading the code and about who might need to understand it down the line.

- Arw you working as part of a team? In a company that develops software? Talk to your team and check existing style guides, naming guides and the existing codebase for similar patterns. Following local conventions helps your teammates, other employees and future maintainers understand your code better.
- You are probably not the first person to be using the programming language, framework or libraries you are using. Find a universal style guide for the language, like PEP for python or the Microsoft naming guide for C# and see if it answers your question. Find other projects using your language or framework and see how they name their functions and patterns. Adhering to that means that other developers coming into your code - either new hires, open source contributors or even just people you ask for help on SO - can easily understand you.
- Is your app on a specific domain? Like finance, cyber security, crypto currency, or whatever? Check out projects on this domain to see if there are common *cross language* naming conventions. For the same reasons as above: you want your code to be as readable as possible to the *right people*.

---

As for your specific question - I'm not familiar with the style of having method pairs named `DoX` and `ProceedDoX`, and their meanings will not be intuitive to me from my experience, but specific languages or domains might be using it.

I can't offhand think of specific naming patterns for this, but I've seen pairs where `DoX` was matched with `DoXNoChecks`, `DoXInternal` or `DoXImpl`, each with their own advantages and disadvantages.

Answer (score 0):

As a reader of your code, I expect a function with a specific name, to do the thing the name suggests. I would be surprised to find that the function only validates whether the actual function can be called.

It is also rather error prone, because the actual function that does the work, can be called from elsewhere and no validation will be performed.

Cleaning up large functions by breaking them up is good practice, but break up sections that make sense on their own. In your example the check for someCondition1 and someCondition2 are better candidates to extract into separate functions.

```
private void doWork() {

    checkCondition1(...);
    checkCondition2(...);
    
    try {
        // handle actual doWork logic
    } catch(Exception e) {
         // Error handling
    }
}

private void checkCondition1(...) {
    // perform checks
}

private void checkCondition2(...) {
    // perform checks
}
```

Comment: A call to `function` here *does* perform the function - it delegates to a second function after validation but that's fine. But it still does the thing.

Comment: @AvnerShahar-Kashtan if it delegates to another function, it *does not* do the thing. It does another thing (validation) but not what the name of the function suggests. By delegating, the end result might be the same, but it's performed by methods which do different things then their names suggest. This answer is basically the same as Flater's; we posted within a minute of eachother.

Comment: It's hard to make the case in either direction with a generic name like `function`. If I have a function called `ShutdownAccount`, and I call it and it shuts down the account, the name is *correct*. And if it needs to verify that the account doesn't have any outstanding transactions first, and then calls `ChangeAccountStatus` or `ShutdownAccountImpl`, calling it `ShutdownAccount` is still the proper name.

Comment: I copied the name `function` from the question, but I agree it's not the best choice, so I renamed it in my example to doWork(). Not going to discuss your new example in the comments, but I would never approve a PR with a function named `ShutdownAccountImpl`.